# Is it "combinations between" or "combinations of" in the following context?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should be used with **combinations** in the following sentence?

> We should consider all possible combinations **between/of** different
>   versions of A on the one hand, and different versions of B on the other.

Generally, "combination of" seems to be way more popular.

[image: Google Ngram chart]

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=combinations%20of%2Ccombinations%20between&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccombinations%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccombinations%20between%3B%2Cc0)

But in the above context, we have different versions on each side of the combination, which is why I think maybe "combination between" is a better choice. So, notice please that the expressions *on the one hand* and *on the other* are crucial to the context and thus to my question.

Comment: @TotZam Is the answer there final?

Comment: Based on the answers given there, it seems like "combination of" is the correct choice.

Comment: @TotZam Yes, but is the answer there correct? Also, as I said in the new edition, there is something different in my context.

Comment: I see what you are saying. Are you comparing the difference between the combinations of A and the combinations of B, or are you creating one big group of combinations of A and B?

Comment: @TotZam " combining different versions of A on one hand and different versions of B on the other hand". So I guess it is the former.

Comment: A is one version, B is a different version. If you say different VERSIONS of A, you are saying there is more than one version A, there could be five versions of A, but they are all different. This is not logical. It's grammatical in English but it is illogical in life.

Comment: In addition, I had to correct the idiomatic expression: On *the* one hand.... on *the* other. I think you should consider visiting [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) and ask your questions there. You ask specific questions about a single point, ignoring that there may be several other problems in the text; e.g. "version of A" vs. "versions of A"

Comment: `... all possible different combinations between A on the one hand, and B on the other.` this implies there are only two combinations, this seems to contradict the premise `we should consider ALL possible combinations`. If instead there are more than two combinations available, then use the preposition  "of"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I used A and B most roughly for two sides. Consider "all possible combinations between different versions of contextualism/non-contextualism on the one hand and different versions of externalism/internalism on the other". So, you say we have to use "combinations of" anyway? What about all cases of "combinations between" on the web?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Please see https://jakubmarian.com/on-the-one-hand-on-one-hand/  Before seeing it, I had in mind the same consideration about the first *the* being illogical.

Comment: @Mari-LouA There are two sides in each of which we have a different theory. So two main theories each explain a different aspect of a particular phenomenon.. But there are different versions of each of these two theories. When we want to explain the phenomenon, we take one version in the first side and combine it with one version in the other side.

Comment: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/on_the_one_(or_the_other)_hand Always best to check a dictionary, and the author even says that the article is preferred but instead you go ahead and write "on one hand... on the other..." You seem to want to do the opposite of what everyone else says. :) As for your "versions of A" then you should rephrase it. Include the comment above in our question, which is "context", (see Dan Bron's tips for writing a good question) and which is always important in any question about the usage of English.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the confusion arises as a result of breaking down the steps of the process.  If I understand correctly, what you're trying to do is create every possible combination of two you can get by taking one item from set A and one item from set B.  (In mathematics, this is called the **[cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)**.) Then, you want to do one of two things:

1. Compare all of these matches against each other
2. Compare the parts of each match with each other.

**Combine** in this case means *To couple or join two or more things together* (OED).

**Compare** can mean *To mark or point out the similarities and differences of (two or more things)* (OED)

Because *combining* is the act of lumping objects together into one entity, the word does not fit well with a preposition like *between*.  The outcome of *combining* two objects is a single object.  There's no rule that says you can't use *between* in this case, but I doubt that it would improve the clarity of the statement, so I would advise sticking with *of*.

You could certainly use *of* without a loss of clarity.  Because you say "we should **consider** each combination," there is an implication that *for each combination, you will do some sort of comparison [either among the combinations, or between the parts of each combination]*.

> We should **consider** all possible **combinations** **of** different versions of A on the one hand, and different versions of B on the other.

However, the statement might benefit from clarifying what exactly is being considered.  Is it, (1) comparing the matches against each other, or (2) comparing each item from set A against each item from set B?  Also, if you're only looking for combinations with one item from each set, you might consider using the word **matches** to avoid confusion.

If you want to do the first, you might write:

> We should **compare** all possible combinations of different versions of A and different versions of B.

If you want to do the second:

> We should **consider** all possible combinations of different versions of A and different versions of B, and for each **match** we should **compare between** the parts.

It might be wordier that way, but cutting words at the expense of clarity is often not worth it.  If you're comfortable using technical terminology, you could shorten the phrase further with some variation of this:

> We should consider the **cartesian product** of A versions and B versions and **compare the parts of each match**.